# How to use Text Finder as part of an if statement in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am creating a log sheet of inventory that leaves the room I work in. The sheet titled "Pulls" is a form where the product SKU is entered in cell B2, along with some other information (quantity taken, date, and who took it. This information is copied (using an "enter" button) onto another sheet, "SMT-P", essentially a big list containing any inputs entered into the Pulls sheet. The code that copies this info from sheet to sheet works fine.

Imagine someone has to take 4 of SC0007 on 3/5/24. On the Pulls sheet, SC0007(SKU) is entered in cell B2, 4(quantity) is entered in cell B3, and the 3/5/24(date) is entered in cell B4. An "enter" button copies these inputs into the SMT-P sheet. If the SMT-P sheet started empty, the SKU copies into cell A3, the quantity copies into cell B3, and the date copies into cell C3. The next input entered would copy into cell A4, B4, and C4 respectively. SMT-P sheet is essentially a list of all products that have left the room over multiple days.

Before the "enter" button can be pressed, I need a button that runs a function that will search the SMT-P sheet for any SKUs matching the input in B2(pulls) that were entered on the same day as the date entered in B4(pulls). If the function finds there is a matching SKU that was entered on the same day, cell B2 on the Pulls sheet should highlight red to let the user know it is the SKU they entered has already been pulled from the room on that day.

Here is my code:

```
`function findSKU(){
  const ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const searchTerm=ws.getSheetByName("Pulls").getRange("B2").getDisplayValue
  const searchRange=ws.getSheetByName("SMT-P").getRange("A3:A").getDisplayValues


 if (searchRange.match(searchTerm) && (the cells two to the right of the cells containing the search     term is today's date. i have no clue how to go about coding this condition))
    {ss.ssForm.getRange("B2").setBackground("red")}
```

}
`
It does not work, like at all. Any tips or help is much appreciated, I am a beginner. There is probably a better way to go about it than the method I tried.

Thank you

I tried using text finder but cannot figure out how to get it to work with an "if" statement (if matching sku/date is found, highlight cell B2 red.) I think there are problems with my syntax but I do not understand how to fix it.

Comment: "the cells two to the right of the cells containing the search term is today's date" - Is it always today's date? Also, what's the date format?